# Show counter onChange input box with a current defaultValue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

How do I get the value to be the inital value first form the data of the API and then change when the user starts typing or deleting text?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const MyInput = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  const initial = dataFromApi.length

  const total = 1000

  const counterChange = (e) => {
    setCounter(initial.length + e.target.value.length)
  }

  return(
    <>{counter}/{total}<input defaultValue={dataFromApi} onChange={counterChange}/></>
  )

}

export default MyInput
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-napier-3nekx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the initial length to the useState hook

```
const initial = dataFromApi.length
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initial)
```

If you expect your API data to change you could use a useEffect hook to reset the length state when API data changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(dataFromApi.length);
}, [dataFromApi.length]);
```

and there's no need to add the initial value in the onChange handler if you want to show the current length of the entered text

`setCounter(e.target.value.length)`